# I have even function $f(x)$ and have to decide which statements are right

Tags: functions

I have even function $f(x)$ and have to decide which statements are right:

1. $(-1)\cdot f(x)$ is even function
2. $f(x)\cdot f(x)$ is even function
3. $f(x)+5$ is even function
4. $f(x)\cdot f(x)$ is odd function

I think that statements #1 and #2 are right, but #3 and #4 are not

3. if we have $-x^2$, it is odd function, but once we add $5$, it will not be anymore
4. this is not true, because product of two odd function is odd function

Am I right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If a statement is false, you should be able to produce a specific counterexample.  If it is true, it requires a proof.  Also, why do you think the function defined by $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = -x^2$ is an odd function?  Notice that $f(-x) = -(-x)^2 = -x^2 = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the statements from your question are basic properties of even and odd functions, which will be easier to understand after you graph these problems.

When it comes to these 4 statements, we can say that:

- the first one is correct, as you flip the function upside down and it does not change its parity;
- the second is true, as the composition of two even functions is even;
- the third one is true, as you only move $f(x)$ along the $y$ axis, which does not change the parity (hint: graph the $x^2$ and try to move it 5 grids up);
- the fourth is false, as it is the counter-statement of the second one.

Comment: The zero function can be both even and odd, so it is not the case that showing a function is even proves that it cannot be odd.

Answer (score 1):

If a statement is true, it requires a proof.  If it is false, it requires a counterexample.

To prove that a function is even, we must show that for each $x$ in its domain, $f(-x) = f(x)$.

**Claim:** If $f$ is an even function, then the function $g$ defined by $g(x) = (-1)f(x)$ is an even function.

**Proof.**  Since $f$ is an even function, for each $x$ in its domain, $f(-x) = f(x)$.  Then $$g(-x) = (-1)f(-x) = (-1)f(x) = g(x)$$ for each $x$ in the domain of $g$.  Therefore, $g$ is an even function.$\blacksquare$

Can you write a proof that the function $h$ defined by $h(x) = f(x) \cdot f(x)$ is even?

The third statement is actually true.  Try to produce a proof.

The fourth statement is false.  To see this, consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$.  It is an even function since $f(-x) = (-x)^2 = x^2 = f(x)$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  If the function $k$ defined by $k(x) = f(x) \cdot f(x) = x^2 \cdot x^2 = x^4$ is odd, then $k(-x) = -k(x)$ for each $x$ in its domain.  However, $k(-1) = (-1)^4 = 1 = 1^4 = k(1)$, so $k$ is not an odd function.